# ActionBarSherlock old title bar still visivle on older android versions

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have my interface implemented with ActionBarSherlock, and it works great with the newest android versions. But this android 2.1 to android 2.3, it keeps the older title bar, I can't find a way to remove it.

I've already tried:

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            if (actionBar != null) {
                this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            }

        }
```

With the android Window object and Sherlock's Window object.
Can't make thar bar go away...

Comment: What theme are you specifying in your Manifest? Are you using the Sherlock ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

res/values/style.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" />
</resources>
```

res/values-v11/style.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" />
</resources>
```

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have to use "Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar" and there is no "Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar.NoTitleBar".

Comment: I'm using in res/values/style.xml: `<style name="MyThemeWihoutTitle" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>`

Comment: **This lead me to the answer**, thanks! this:`<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>` will remove the old title bar, KEEPING the (sherlock)actionbar

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.NoActionBar">
```

so you can apply this theme to your activity in AndroidManifest file:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp"></activity>
```